# Query for orders that contain a product without using sub-query

Tags: t-sql

```
Order
-----
OrderId

OrderDetail
-----------
OrderDetailId
OrderId
ProductId
```

How do I write a query that returns all orders that contain a specific product without using a sub-query?

I don't want to write a sub-query because I want to encapsulate the query in a view and use a WHERE clause on the view to supply the product id instead of having a stored procedure and supplying a parameter.

I figure the only way to do this is to join orders to details and GROUP BY on order but even then I don't know how to have the aggregate column resolve to whether the product is amongst the order details.

Comment: I don't understand why a subquery is out of the question. How does it restrict you? Can you give an example of the code you tried (and did not work)?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use the view with something like `SELECT * FROM Orders_without_a_product_View WHERE product_id = X;` ?

Comment: Yes exactly. I don't see how to get a product id outside the view into the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea about efficiency<sup>*</sup> but a view like this:

```
CREATE VIEW 
    Orders_with_a_product_View AS
SELECT 
    p.ProductID, o.*
FROM
    dbo.Product AS p
  JOIN
    dbo.[Order] AS o
      ON EXISTS
         ( SELECT 1
           FROM dbo.OrderDetail AS od
           WHERE od.OrderID = o.OrderID
             AND od.ProductId = p.ProductId
         ) ;
```

would allow you to use it with:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Orders_with_a_product_View 
WHERE ProductID = X ;
```

(*Regarding efficiency: Hopefully the optimizer will "push-down" the condition and not do a cross join of all products and orders.)

---

It might be better to follow a simpler road, like this:

```
CREATE VIEW 
    Order_Product_IDs AS
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ProductID, OrderID
FROM
    dbo.OrderDetail ;
```

and the utilize it with:

```
SELECT o.* 
FROM dbo.Order_Product_IDs AS op 
  JOIN dbo.[Order] AS o
    ON o.OrderID = op.OrderID
WHERE op.ProductID = X ;
```

Comment: A join on an exists. That's amazing.

Comment: I assumed that `(OrderID, ProductID)` is not unique in OrderDetails. Otherwise, a simple join would be enough (and the Product table unneeded).

Comment: The optimizer is only using the product id to seek in the products table. Maybe I can jig it to do something smarter.

(OrderID, ProductID) are in fact not unique. Some attributes further distinguish products with the same id.

Comment: I will try your second query. The first works with index seeks until I swap out the order table for an order view at which point the optimizer seems to lose touch with the ability to use the product id smartly. The query goes from 1 second to 7.

Comment: I'd think an index on `(ProductID, OrderID)` would be helpful. Do you have such an index?

Comment: I had one for product ID and it said it already had orderId. I don't understand what it was doing. Anyhow I deleted it and added (ProductID, OrderID) and now the query with the view is down to 2 seconds even though its still doing index scans. So that's an improvement which will do for now.

Comment: Its frustrating that the table view seems to add so many joins to the query that it doesn't realise there's a faster method of filtering.

Comment: Well, if you have views inside views inside views ..., it's like adding layers of complexity. The more complex the query, the more chances are the optimizer might not find the best plan. But without explicit details of what you do (CREATE TABLE and VIEW statements, indexes, execution plans), I don't think we can help more.

Comment: That's for sure :)

Comment: Aha... your second query nailed it.

Comment: `Orders_without_a_product_View` seems a misnomer if its purpose is to find orders *with* a specific product. Or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @AndriyM Thnx. At first, I thought it was the opposite (and had used NOT EXISTS). The code was corrected, the name not ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a table-valued function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.OrdersWithProduct (@ProductId int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
  SELECT
    o.*
  FROM
    dbo.[Order] AS o
  WHERE EXISTS
    (
      SELECT
        *
      FROM
        dbo.OrderDetail AS od
      WHERE
        od.OrderId = o.OrderId
        AND od.ProductId = @ProductId
    )
);
```

And then use it to find orders containing one specific product:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  dbo.OrdersWithProduct(@SomeProductId)
;
```

or any of a *list* of specific products:

```
SELECT
  p.ProductId,
  f.OrderId
FROM
  dbo.MyCustomProductList AS p
  CROSS APPLY dbo.OrdersWithProduct(p.ProductId)
;
```